# Allow users to create blade files with safe limited access

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-blade

I've been searching for a way to allow my users to create, via the UI, what are basically `blade` files that will be processed like `blade` views to output html - for the purpose of producing emails.

However, of course the normal way of processing a `blade` file technically gives the creator of that `blade` file access to the entirety of PHP, to the entirety of my environment, etc.

What I really want is to pass in this blade template and only a couple variables, and as the blade file gets processed it ONLY has access to those variables I pass in and nothing else. They can loop through any array-type variables using `{% foreach ... %}` syntax, but they won't have global PHP/Laravel access.

I know there are alternate template engines that are built for this purpose, and I'm interested in those too, but I'm also interested if there's a way to process Blade files like this, with limited access.

Comment: So you're looking for recommandations ? processing blade files with limited access. that's another definition for "template engine" or "page builder"

Comment: @N69S the main point of my question is, is there a way to use blade itself, not a different engine, inside of Laravel while giving it this sort of safe limited access? If that's not possible, then I'm of course going to have to look into non-blade alternatives.

Comment: I'm pretty sure blade was designed for the developers and not for users, and thus even if you were able to limit what it can do, they would be hacks and workarounds; I think your are better off creating one yourself :)

Comment: You can make you own page builder that creates/uses blade files.

Comment: on second thought, I think you can use [twig](https://twig.symfony.com) without the _core_ extension and creating one for yourself

Comment: You can decompose your email builder into sections (combination of image + texte) and each combination have its blade file. and render it on the fly.